# Laravel Database Fetch Using Foreign Key on Specific Id

Tags: laravel-5

I have make category model and product model .

The relationship :

Category has many product

Product belongs to category

My Category.php

```
 public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

my Product.php

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

My routes :

```
Route::get('categories/{id}','ShopController@items');
```

My ShopController@items

```
            public function items($id)
{
    $products = Product::find($id);
    $categories = Category::find($id);
    return view('shop.togo',compact('products','categories'));
}
```

In my togo.blade.php

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Products belongs to {{$categories->name}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
<td>{{$product->name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@stop
```

How to list out the products under the specific categories? if the categories id were 1 , if i pass the value localhost:8000/categories/1 , how to show the products that has foreign key(categories_id) that belong the specific categories?

Any feedback really appreciated

Comment: Do you by any chance mean $categories = Category::find($id)->with('product');

Comment: how to display it in view?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a hasMany relationship you have to iterate inside an iteration like :

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
<td>{{$product->name}}</td>
</tr>
@foreach($product->category as $category)
{{$category->name}}
@endforech
@endforeach
```